# how to upvote a downvoted answer? or otherwise suggest best criteria in voting

Tags: discussion, locked-votes

It happened to me to land on this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/split-string-based-on-delimiter-in-bash)

The OP was trying to split a string of semicolon separated emails, however he put in his question the sentence `How do I split a string based on a delimiter in Bash?` which was probably what drove google in my search as I was trying to understand exactly this, only applied to a string which contains spaces.

Some answer didn't work at all, while others worked perfectly even on my string with spaces in it, among them there were some good answers, only missing something to work on a string with spaces.
Of course I downvoted those which didn't work at all and upvoted the working ones.
Then I thought to downvote also those 'almost ok':

I mean, one of them is

```
echo "bla@some.com;john@home.com" | sed -e 's/;/\n/g'
bla@some.com
john@home.com
```

I downvoted this to motivate the answerer to add
1) how to create an array (the OP needed an array as well to loop over it)

```
arrIN=( $( echo "$IN" | sed -e 's/;/\n/g' ) )
```

2) to use

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

for string containing spaces.

I thought this because maybe people can land to this page searching a more generic scenario, as I did.

I added a comment while downvoting and thought to upvote them later if they decide to edit the answer adding those further details.

Then I realized I cannot upvote a downvoted answer, as I receive the following advice:

```
You last voted on this answer
Sep 3 at 10:00
Your vote is now locked in
unless this answer is edited
```

I googled and it seems a wanted feature, so .. is my behavior wrong?

If so: how can I now remove my downvote over those answers which were correct?

Maybe I would not upvote some of them because they are not best choices in a more general scenario, but they are correct for the question over email and they don't deserve a downvote.

Comment: "unless this answer is edited" - if and when the post is updated, then you can remove your downvote.

Comment: how do I know that? Could I receive an alert when the post is edited or must I come back from time to time and check?

Comment: You could favorite the question (though that does not filter out other events that might happen). Other than that, you would have to check back from time to time.

Comment: You don't. I think there was a feature request for a notification when a post you downvoted is edited. But it probably fell on deaf ears.

Comment: That's exactly why I prefer leaving comments instead of downvoting 'almost correct' answers - or edit them into 'correct' state, if possible. Downvoting, in my opinion, should be reserved only for the answers that either _completely_ miss the problem in question, or try to promote the _bad_ (not non-working, just bad inherently) ideas of how to solve it.

Comment: @raina77ow After reading your comments I think that the idea of the authors of SO behind locking-votes could be: you can downvote an 'almost correct' answer commenting what's wrong, then the answerer can decide to edit his/her answer, only then (after edit) you can alter you vote .. it can have a sense

Comment: @LucaBorrione Well, it was the original intent I guess. ) Unfortunately, while quite sensible in theory, sometimes it jsut doesn't work in practice.

Comment: @raina77ow You are completely right. It doesn't sound a good practice at all. At least if the authors of SO want to keep vote-locking, then imho the 'notification after edit' is a MUST! Otherwise it's a hell for the voter to check back aaaall his/her downvotes given to incite a correction ..

Comment: Can't you edit the answer now? Then you can remove your downvote from it afterwards. (I'm not sure if that works, btw.)

Comment: @Mr Lister: good idea, but I cannot test it as my edits are still placed in a peer review queue (until 2000 rep I think)